# why is this redirecting me even if the user is not in the database?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to build a login verification form with a mongoDB database. And whenever the user logs in with the correct details he should be redirected to the homepage and if it is wrong, he should stay in the same page. Everything works fine with storing the user and veryfing it from server side. But whenever I try to log the user in even if the user is incorrect it still redirects me.

Here is the login form:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './login.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    const history = useHistory()


    const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
      setUsername(e.target.value)
    }

    const onChangePassword = (e) => {
      setPassword(e.target.value)
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      const users = {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/login', users)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    }

    const loginUser = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users/user", {
        withCredentials: true
      }).then(res => {
        setData(res)
        if(res.status === 200) return history.push("/home")
        else return history.push("/login")
      })
    }
    console.log(data)

    return (
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitter-logo-png/twitter-logo-vector-png-clipart-1.png" className="twitterlogo____image"/>
          <h1 className="login_____headertext">Log in to Twitter</h1>
          <div className="placeholder_____global">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input className="placeholder____div" placeholder="Phone, email or username" onChange={onChangeUsername}/>
            <div>
              <input className="placeholder____div" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={onChangePassword}/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button className="twitter___loginbuttonpage" onClick={loginUser}>Log in</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div className="forgetPassword_____div">
              <p>Forgot password?</p>
              <p>·</p>
              <p>Sign up for Twitter</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

server side passport authentication:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Users = require('../models/users.model.js')
const passport = require("passport")

require('../authentication/passportConfig.js')(passport)


router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Users.find()
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
})

router.route('/user').get((req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user)
})

router.route('/login').post((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local" , (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.send("No user exists")
    else {
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send("Succesfully Authenticated")
      })
    }
  })(req, res, next)
})

router.route('/add').post(async(req,res) => {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
  const username = req.body.username
  const password = hashedPassword
  const email = req.body.email
  const phone = req.body.phone
  const monthOfBirth = req.body.monthOfBirth
  const dayOfBirth = req.body.dayOfBirth
  const yearOfBirth = req.body.yearOfBirth

  const newUsers = new Users({
    username,
    password,
    email,
    phone,
    monthOfBirth,
    dayOfBirth,
    yearOfBirth
  })

  newUsers.save()
  .then (() => res.json("User Added"))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error' + err))
})



module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you click on the Login button, it executes two methods:

- loginUser(): Because it is being called via `onClick` attribute of the button
- onSubmit(): Because it is being called on form's submission via `onSubmit`

Now let's talk about the server-side of things. The `loginUser` method on client-side calls the `/user` endpoint which always returns a 200 status code because all it does is send back a user from the request via `res.send(req.user)`, while `onSubmit` method on client-side actually triggers authentication through the `/login` endpoint.

On the client side, the implementation of `loginUser` method checks for the `status` `200` of the response via:

```
if(res.status === 200) return history.push("/home")
    else return history.push("/login")
```

In this scenario, since `/user` endpoint that `loginUser` calls will always simply send the response back via `res.send(req.user)`, it is bound to always have `status` equals to `200`, hence, the `if-else` expression on the client-side will never execute the `else` part of it, and continue to redirect to `/home`, irrespective of the correctness of the credentials.

### Solution

A better approach IMO would be to avoid executing 2 methods on clicking of Login button, and only have `onSubmit` method executed on form submission on the client-side, letting it trigger `/login` endpoint to handle the authentication and then according to the API's response, managing redirection to `/login` page or `/home` page.